# Can I map properties directly in Java Stream?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream, hibernate-mapping

In my Spring Boot project, I use the following map:

```
public void create(List<EmployeeRequest> request) {
    final List<Employee> employees = request.stream()
            .map(r -> new Employee(r.getName(),
                    r.getEmail(),
                    r.getCountry(),
                    r.getAge()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
}
```

Here is the related classes:

```
public class EmployeeRequest {
    String name;
    String email;
    String country;
    int age;
}
```

```
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String country;

    private int age;

    public Employee(String name, String email, String country, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.country = country;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

As the field names are the same, I tried to make a mapping directly using class instead of each field as shown below, but I make a mistake I think related to Functional method:

```
public void create(List<EmployeeRequest> request) {
    final List<Employee> employees = request.stream()
            .map(Employee::new) // Cannot resolve constructor 'Employee'
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
}
```

But I am getting "*Cannot resolve constructor 'Employee'*" error on the following line:

```
.map(Employee::new)
```

So, is it possible to make this kind of mapping via Java stream?

**Update:** I moved `toEntity()` method to a separate class a shown below, but get error if I don't make it static:

```
public class EmployeeRequestMapper {

    public Employee mapToEntity(EmployeeRequest request) {
        return new Employee(request.getName(), request.getEmail(), request.getCountry(), request.getAge());
    }
}
```

And I use it as shown below:

```
public void create(List<EmployeeRequest> request) {
    final List<Employee> employees = request.stream()
            .map(EmployeeRequestMapper::mapToEntity)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
}
```

So, do I have to make `mapToEntity` static or is there a proper way using that method in my service?

Comment: Where's your constructor?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: @Baldrick you need contractor like that `public Employee(EmployeeRequest request) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that it's a rest API and your Request class functions as a DTO. So what I like to do is just create a method `toEntity` in the Request/DTO class and then I have a pretty easy mapping and the responsibility is on the Request/DTO side. In your case it would look something like this:

```java
public class EmployeeRequest {
    String name;
    String email;
    String country;
    int age;

    public Employee toEntity() {
        return new Employee(this.name, this.email, this.country, this.age);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```java
public void create(List<EmployeeRequest> request) {
    final List<Employee> employees = request.stream()
            .map(EmployeeRequest::toEntity)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
}
```

---

But if you want to make your way work you could create a constructor in `Employee` that just takes `EmployeeRequest`. But I don't like this solution because I think the Entity should not need to know about the other class.
But in case you don't care about this, just add a constructor in your Employee:

```java
public Employee(EmployeeRequest request) {
    this.name = request.getName();
    this.email = request.getEmail();
    this.country = request.getCountry();
    this.age = request.getAge();
}
```

Comment: Well I did vote up for you because I already have seen very bad questions that really deserve a downvote. And yours was good. You gave us all the information necessary; Code, a little description of what you want and a specific question. My guess is that the downvotes came because of the fact that this question is quite easy to solve (if you're using intellij you probably could get it sovled by it) but that's not a reason for me because everyone started somewhere.

Comment: So separate class means it's not in your Entity nor in Request? I guess that's the case since it's only working with static because you don't have an instannce of this separate class to call the method on. Therefore it makes sense that static is required. Static methods are methods you can call without having an instance of the object.

Comment: I think the Request class is a good place since it knows what it needs and especially on a request you already have an instance to work on. On the response side you had to make it static or use constructor because you want to go from the Entity to a new instance of DTO/Response. But it's also fine to use a Mapper class and for this I even prefer to make it static (If it's just mapping from object A to object B and doesn't have a sort of configuration).

Comment: No as I said static is fine here. You don't need to try to avoid static it can be very handy and improve the readability (But ofc it can also destroy the whole concept of OOP when overused).

Comment: I never had the need to use one because it's pretty easy to add some mapping methods, so I can't tell you something about this

Answer (score 1):

`map` accepts a function that is supposed to receive the `EmployeeRequest` and returns back the  instance of `Employee`

Something like this:

```java
Employee createEmployeeFromRequest(EmployeeRequest request) {...}
```

So if you want to use a constructor, you should create one that maps the request to the Employee:

```java
public class Employee {

      public Employee(EmployeeReqeuest request) {
          ...
      }
}
```

Then you can map with `Employee::new` which is a method reference here - it "refers" this constructor - without that it won't work